# Magento 1 : Http 500 error after installing extension of size chart

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, http-error-500

Making website on Magento 1.9.
i installed an extension of sizechart by extension mall but after installing it gives an error of HTTP 500 error and after uncommenting

## ini_set('display_errors', 1);

```
( it shows following error )
```

> Fatal error: Class 'ExtensionsMall_SizeChart_Helper_Data' not found in
> /home/iranucom/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

can anyone guide how can i solve the same.

Comment: Is compilation on in your Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to first check that in extension helper file exist or not.

Go to `ExtensionsMall/SizeChart/Helper/Data.php` where class `ExtensionsMall_SizeChart_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` should be exist.

Also check in `ExtensionsMall/SizeChart/etc/config.xml` file that helper is defined or not as below:

```
<helpers>
    <sizechart>
        <class>ExtensionsMall/SizeChart/Helper</class>
    </sizechart>
</helpers>
```